# About UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, device, capability

If app add two items into UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities array in the info.plist file, one is armv7(the default),another is bluetooth-le.That's explain app only available on devices with BLE4.0  ? And whether other devices without BLE4.0 can download this app from app store or run it?

Answer (score 3):

That's correct. Only devices with those capabilities will be able to install your app. This is explained in the [UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html) documentation. Quoting:

> UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities (Array or Dictionary - iOS) lets iTunes and the App Store know which device-related features an app requires in order to run. iTunes and the mobile App Store use this list to prevent customers from installing apps on a device that does not support the listed capabilities.
>
> If you use an array, the presence of a given key indicates the corresponding feature is required. If you use a dictionary, you must specify a Boolean value for each key. If the value of this key is true, the feature is required. If the value of the key is false, the feature must not be present on the device. In both cases, omitting a key indicates that the feature is not required but that the app is able to run if the feature is present.